# Laravel 5.2 belongsTo relationship Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel-5

I looked at some other similar posts, but can't seem to solve this one. New to Laravel.
I have my view:

```
@foreach($logged_jobs as $logged_job)
    <li>{{ $logged_job->a_score->sport }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Model1:

```
class joblogs extends Model
{
   public function a_score()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\scores');
   }
}
```

Model2:

```
class scores extends Model
{
    public function loggs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\joblogs');
    }
}
```

I've tried naming the a_score() method several names. 
If I only output `<li>{{ $logged_job }}</li>`it works, displays all the rows in the joblogs table, but when I try to add the relationship to get the name, it gives the error.

[image: Scores data here]
[image: Logs data here]

So view should read:
Tennis
Tennis
Tennis
Rugby
Rugby etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because you need to specify the relation fields ...

```
public function a_score()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\scores', 'scores_id');
}
```

please review the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) to learn more about the relations in Elouquent ...

Comment: there is only one score record for each score_id in the logs. Data attached.